# H2 timestamp - Always inserting (or getting) the current Date

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot, h2

I am new in SpringBoot and I create an application using embedded DB H2.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_occurrence (
   id     bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   where  varchar(100),
   when   timestamp null
);
```

I use this class to insert values, but whatever I insert I always get the current date when I do `occurrence.getWhen()`

```
int numOfRowsAffected = jdbcTemplate.update(
    "insert into t_occurrence (ID, where, when) " 
    + " values (?,?,?);",
    id,
    occurrence.getWhere(),
    occurrence.getWhen()
);

if (numOfRowsAffected==1) return id;
else return -1;
```

Even hardcoding the time

```
int numOfRowsAffected = jdbcTemplate.update(
        "insert into t_occurrence (ID, where, when) " 
        + " values (?,?,''2012-09-17 18:47:52.69');",
        id,
        occurrence.getWhere(),
        occurrence.getWhen()
    );

    if (numOfRowsAffected==1) return id;
    else return -1;



public class Occurrence {



private Long id;


private Date when;


private String where;



public Long getId() {

    return id;

}



public void setId(Long id) {

   this.id = id;

}


public Date getWhen() {

   return when;

}



public void setWhen(Date when) {

this.when = when;

}



public String getWhere() {

return where;

}



public void setWhere(String where) {

this.where = where;

}

}
```

Comment: How is `getWhen()` defined in occurrence class?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Type of "Date" and Type of "Time" for when not use "timestamp"

Type of "timestamp" is auto general by server

Comment: but DateTime is not present in H2 types:
INT Type
BOOLEAN Type
TINYINT Type
SMALLINT Type
BIGINT Type
IDENTITY Type
DECIMAL Type
DOUBLE Type
REAL Type
TIME Type
DATE Type
TIMESTAMP Type
TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE Type
BINARY Type
OTHER Type
VARCHAR Type
VARCHAR_IGNORECASE Type
CHAR Type
BLOB Type
CLOB Type
UUID Type
ARRAY Type
GEOMETRY Type

Comment: There is DATE Type and TIME Type for H2 types

Comment: Time Type like "hh:mm:ss" , DATE Type like "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: but I need also to store the time

Comment: Create two columns ...when01 Time,when02 DATE